# нужно перенаправить пользователя на другую страницу при нажатии кнопки, очень важно также проверить соответствие паролей

Tags: javascript, html, функции

В общем, у меня есть код регистрации формы пользователя, при нажатии кнопки регистрации надо будет перенаправить пользователя на другую страницу, с этим я могу справиться. Но есть одна проблемка, получается когда еще новый страницы не было, в коде было написано, что с нажатием этой кнопки надо будет проверить соответствуют ли пароли, которые написал пользователь ( javascript функция) . А теперь мне надо чтобы и то  и то одновременно происходило, но не получается. Можете помочь, я просто только начинаю, еще не сильно разбираюсь, делаю чисто по примерам и тому что читаю и учу.
Вот код самой кнопки:

```html
<button type="submit" id="submit_button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" disabled onclick="return validate()">Register</button>
```

Вот javascript функции:

```js
function validate(){
  var password = document.getElementById("exampleInputPassword1").value;
  var confirmPassword = document.getElementById("exampleInputPassword2").value;
    if (password != confirmPassword) {
        alert("Passwords do not match.");
        return false;
    }
    }
  return true;
}
```

А вот тут код простого перенаправления:

```
<button type="submit" id="submit_button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" onclick="window.location.href='success.html'">Register</button>
```

Мне нужно чтобы 2 действия ( проверка пароля и перенаправления на другую страницу) происходили одновременно, можете помочь как это написать?

Answer (score 0):

У вас была лишняя закрывающая фигурная скобка

`onclick="validate()"`

```js
function validate() {
  var password = document.getElementById("exampleInputPassword1").value;
  var confirmPassword = document.getElementById("exampleInputPassword2").value;
  if (password == confirmPassword) {
    window.location.href = 'success.html'
  };
  alert("Passwords do not match.")
};
```